# SQL Inner Join request doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm new in mysql and php and I have a problem with a query. I want to get nearby locations which I am calculating with the Harversine formula. This all is working, but now I want to show the specific stores which are associated with the locations. This is the relevant part:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT 'Location.id', latitude, longitude, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude )
 - radians('%s') ) + sin(radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM(SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM Location WHERE latitude Between '%s' AND '%s' AND longitude Between '%s' AND '%s') AS cut
    JOIN Store ON 'Location.storeID' = 'Store.id'
    WHERE 6371 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude )
     - radians('%s') ) + sin(radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) < '%s' ORDER BY distance",
```

Without the JOIN statement, this works fine. But if I use the JOIN statement, I get an empty array. Does anyone know why? Is the statement maybe in the wrong place?
These are my tables:

**Location**

[image]

**Store**

[image]

I will be thankful for any help!

Comment: If it works without the join, try changing the direction of the join - left join/ right join. It may be that there is no matching record in the other table

Comment: Yes, great thanks, that was it. I have to look again into the database and correct it.. Now I have another problem. It shows me not the real location id from the SELECT statement, instead it show me Location.id as a string. Is this because of the ' '? But if I remove the ' ' from SELECT 'Location.id' there's an error that says that the column doesn't exist. But I'm sure that it does exist. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: yes its because of the quotes, you have to remove them or you get the string literal. if mysql says the column doesn't exist, then it dosent

Comment: Use `cut.id` instead of `Location.id`.  Only your inner query is aware of the `Location` table.

Comment: Okay now it works, cut.id did it. Thanks for the help! The last question: Why it is not working when I use Store.id to get the Store ID instead of cut.id to get the Location ID?

Comment: I think this is because of the ' ' around Location.storeID and store.id. If I remove the ' ' and change Location.storeID to cut.storeID. It says: "Unknown column 'cut.storeID' in on clause". Anyone know why? I think the join things are very complicated for a beginner in such a confusing query..